# Not getting the radiobutton checked in the Single choice list android in a custom dialog?

Tags: android, listview, state, radiobuttonlist

I am working on single choice list in a custom dialog but in this when I click on the item I able to get the value,but nothing happens to the radio button in the list.It remains in the unchecked state.Am I missing something in this please help me on this.Thanks.

```
  <ListView android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/list1" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:divider="#781c1e" 
        android:dividerHeight="1px"  
            android:layout_height="310dp" />
```

This is for the row

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip"
android:textColor="#781c1e"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:focusable="true"   
android:textSize="17sp"
```

/>

Comment: add you xml as well as code snippet here, no one will able to get what are you doing.. I don't have android enviornment now, there is a property in xml for listview something like `decedents` add that with value after or before, that should work.

Comment: I have added the code above please have a look into it.

Comment: Thank you Yuvi got it,missed to add in xml.